# Call Python in background from PHP and get output

Tags: php, python, process, callback

I am calling a long-running Python script from inside PHP using the exec command. This works, and I can get output using the $output parameter to the exec command. However, the PHP page starts a loading bar while this exec command is running and I can't update the UI in the meantime. Basically, I am trying to create a loading bar for this Python scripts execution, that needs to update. It doesn't need to update based on the actual loading time, just something to keep the user occupied, so they know something is happening.

How can I start this Python process, and get all of the output, but still have the PHP page able to do other things at the same time?

Comment: I'm not sure about php, but if you're doing a lot of python you might just switch this page to use a python web framework instead of php.

Comment: I thought about this, however, I have an entire PHP system already developed that has extensive analysis tools built in. It would be a lot more work to convert the entire system to PHP

Comment: Can you spawn it in the background and have it write to some sort of log file then have your php script parse that log file to check its progress?  Of course you'll need some way of tracking what that file is named and cleaning it up.

Comment: Thats a possibility. I will try that and let you know. Thanks!!